# Has anyone 'broken' an organism and then restored it to life?

Tags: life

Has anyone 'broken' an organism, rendering it unable to reproduce, then repaired it and observed it returned to being able to reproduce?

An example would be to restore the reproductive capacity to a cell rendered lifeless from radiation.

I've attempted, several times over many years, to find any information about this and all I've found is abiogenesis and the Miller-Urey experiment which is not the question at hand.

If there is another technical term referring to repair of life, versus creation, then I am unaware of it.

ADDENDUM: Clarified question ...limited to reproduction vs. living.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! is expected that you will do some research on your own and share what you have learned when asking questions here. In addition, in a biochemical context organic refers to complex carbon containing molecules — if you got rid of those there would be very little left of an organism ...  ——— Please also take the time to take the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Ok, done. I've edited the question.

Comment: Please not that your edited-in example (which is good) does not match your first sentence: an organism that can't self-replicate anymore is still very much organic, just not alife (kind of like a virus actually).

Comment: @Nikolai So a sterile man is not a life anymore? That's kind of mean. Neuron cells are no longer alive if they don't divide?

Comment: @Cell Of course those would still be alive, I was mostly alluding to OPs example (and thinking of single celled organism for which this type of experiment might be possible). The fact that this usage of the terms oraginc/inorganic and alive/lifeless leads to wrong statements so quickly also shows, why one shouldn't use them in this context together.

Comment: Sounds to me like induced pluripotent stem cells fit your description. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_pluripotent_stem_cell